# MongoDB - service did not respond to the start in a timely fashion

Tags: mongodb, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

This is the third time in a few months that I have had a Dell WMS crash.

Each time it is a problem getting the MongoDB service up and running. I'm getting an error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kclK6.png)

I recently restored the machine from a backup and everything worked without issue for quite some time.

Mongod.cfg:

```
dbpath=C:\Program Files\DELL\WMS\Database\Mongo
logpath=C:\Program Files\DELL\WMS\MongoDb\mongod.log
bind_ip=localhost
auth=true
port=27017
```

If I restore a machine again - the file will be the same and the service will start.
I have tried:
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\DELL\WMS\Database\Mongo" --repair
to fix database but without a success.

The last info from log file looks like:

```
2024-01-18T20:19:59.237+0100 I  CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] got SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN request from Windows Service Control Manager, will terminate after current cmd ends
2024-01-18T20:19:59.348+0100 I  REPL     [serviceShutdown] Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown, waitTime: 10000ms
2024-01-18T20:19:59.523+0100 I  SHARDING [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService
2024-01-18T20:19:59.696+0100 I  CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache
2024-01-18T20:19:59.756+0100 I  NETWORK  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2024-01-18T20:19:59.845+0100 I  NETWORK  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the global connection pool
2024-01-18T20:19:59.845+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder
2024-01-18T20:19:59.860+0100 I  -        [serviceShutdown] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2024-01-18T20:19:59.860+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions
2024-01-18T20:19:59.873+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToDecreaseSnapshotHistoryIfNotNeeded
2024-01-18T20:19:59.881+0100 I  REPL     [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator
2024-01-18T20:19:59.881+0100 I  SHARDING [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD
2024-01-18T20:19:59.900+0100 I  REPL     [serviceShutdown] Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown
2024-01-18T20:19:59.900+0100 I  -        [serviceShutdown] Killing all operations for shutdown
2024-01-18T20:19:59.900+0100 I  COMMAND  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down all open transactions
2024-01-18T20:19:59.900+0100 I  REPL     [serviceShutdown] Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown
2024-01-18T20:19:59.900+0100 I  INDEX    [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator
2024-01-18T20:19:59.952+0100 I  NETWORK  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor
2024-01-18T20:19:59.977+0100 I  CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down free monitoring
2024-01-18T20:19:59.988+0100 I  CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down free monitoring
2024-01-18T20:19:59.997+0100 I  FTDC     [serviceShutdown] Shutting down full-time data capture
2024-01-18T20:19:59.997+0100 I  FTDC     [serviceShutdown] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2024-01-18T20:20:00.018+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the HealthLog
2024-01-18T20:20:00.018+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down the storage engine
2024-01-18T20:20:00.032+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Deregistering all the collections
2024-01-18T20:20:01.511+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Timestamp monitor shutting down
2024-01-18T20:20:01.511+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2024-01-18T20:20:01.514+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2024-01-18T20:20:01.530+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2024-01-18T20:20:01.530+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down journal flusher thread
2024-01-18T20:20:01.596+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Finished shutting down journal flusher thread
2024-01-18T20:20:01.597+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Shutting down checkpoint thread
2024-01-18T20:20:01.597+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] Finished shutting down checkpoint thread
2024-01-18T20:20:10.020+0100 I  STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2024-01-18T20:20:10.021+0100 I  -        [serviceShutdown] Dropping the scope cache for shutdown
2024-01-18T20:20:10.030+0100 I  CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] now exiting
```

What could be the cause of the service failure? Where to look to find information?
I can't keep restoring a copy from a few days ago to ensure month of further work.
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: The config you show is valid. MongoDB configuration file is a YAML file.

Comment: Since the config is valid, and I am not getting any reasonable error what is wrong? 

Nothing is using 27017 port, event viewer is also only informing about timely fashion.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to start it manually, i.e. `mongod.exe --config <your config file>`

Comment: @wernfriedDomscheit
It did not help - command line was running indefinitely. Log is empty.

Comment: No output? Then check (in Powershell) if the service runs the same with `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'MongoDB'} | select Name, DisplayName, State, PathName`

Comment: The only output from using ```mongod.exe --config <your config file>``` is:
<https://imgur.com/ufmhlaL>

Powershell also inform that MongoDB service is stopped:
<https://imgur.com/DdC9QzW>

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots (anyway, the links do not show anything), use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 and put such additional information as edit in your question instead of a comment.

Comment: I just restored virtual machine once again. Let's wait few months and do it again.